# Rails: elasticsearch query block error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

I'm using `elasticsearch` on my rails app and every time I try to add a block to the `def self.search(query)` I get an error:

```
[400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"illegal latitude value [269.99999983236194] for [GeoDistanceSort] for field [distance_type]."}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"prices","node":"AfyW4Pa4S-qKhua-3lY4rg","reason":{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"illegal latitude value [269.99999983236194] for [GeoDistanceSort] for field [distance_type]."}}]},"status":400}
```

Up to this point, it doesn't return an error:

```
def self.search(query)
    __elasticsearch__.search(
        {
            query: {
                multi_match: {
                    query: query,
                    fields: ['title^5', 'description']
                }
            },

            highlight: {
                pre_tags: ['<em>'],
                post_tags: ['</em>'],
                 fields: {
                    title: {},
                    description: {},
                 }
            }

        }
    )
  end
```

if a try to add the `sort block query` inside the model, it returns the above error:

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'
require 'elasticsearch/model'
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader


  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

  index_name Rails.application.class.parent_name.underscore
  document_type self.name.downcase

  settings index: { number_of_shards: 1 } do
    mappings dynamic: 'false' do
      indexes :title, analyzer: 'english', index_options: 'offsets'
      indexes :description, analyzer: 'english'
      indexes :location, type: 'geo_point'
    end
  end

  def location
    [longitude.to_f, latitude.to_f]
  end

  def current_location
    location = request.location
  end


   def self.search(query)
     __elasticsearch__.search(
        {
            query: {
                multi_match: {
                    query: query,
                    fields: ['title^5', 'description']
                }
             },
             sort: [
                {
                    _geo_distance: {
                        "pin.location": ["current_location"],
                        distance: ["radius"],
                        unit: ["km"],
                        mode: ["min"],
                        order: ["asc"],
                        distance_type: ["arc"],

                     }
                }
            ],
            highlight: {
                pre_tags: ['<em>'],
                post_tags: ['</em>'],
                fields: {
                    title: {},
                    description: {},
                }
             }

         }
     )
   end
end

Item.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.delete index: Item.index_name rescue nil


Item.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.create \
  index: Item.index_name,
  body: { settings: Item.settings.to_hash, mappings: Item.mappings.to_hash }

Item.import(force: true)
```

**Update 1**

I have installed the `geocoder gem` to get the location of each address added. So when I create the account with address I get the longitude and latitude coordinates with the following code. After that I added the longitude and langitude columns to the items table, and then when the user uploads an item the coordinates are updated on the items.rb as well.

Here is the `account.rb` setup:

```
geocoded_by :full_address
  after_validation :geocode, if: ->(obj){ obj.full_address.present? }

  def full_address
    [street, city, state, zip_code, country].join(",")
  end
```

Comment: what gem are you using for geolocation?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @eiko... I'm using the `gem geocoder` to get the location.

Comment: The initial error is pretty straight-forward: 269.9 *is* an illegal latitude. Latitude coordinates run from -90 to 90, and longitudes run from -180 to 180. I'm looking into whether geocoder might be giving you illegal coordinates.

Comment: @eiko please check update 1 for more info on the geocoded gem setup.

Comment: could you check your DB to confirm that the latitude / longitude data being saved there does have invalid values (eg 269)? If the database has invalid values, then we know there's something weird happening with geocoder. If it doesn't have invalid values, we know that something weird is happening in your elasticsearch query.

Comment: Yes it is @eiko, please read update 1 for more info! I just updated the question.

Comment: Are you using the default configuration for geocoder? What address is generating the illegal coordinates? I'm honestly stumped.

Comment: Yes Im using the default `geocoded` configuration. I'm guessing there is something wrong with the `query`, but I can't really find what. I just started using elasticsearch and I'm not quite familiar with how I should set it up yet. I would appreciate some pointers on this one!